# Solr - Boost by dynamic field

Tags: solr, lucene

I've added a few dynamic fields to my solr document and I'm trying to boost according these fields and by it's value but I don't see the boost applied in the debug mode, is it possible to boost by these fields/by their values?

Comment: you couldn't boost easily all dynamic fields, you could do that, by listing them one by one in qf param

Comment: something like this? :                        _query_={!dismax%20qf=dynamicFieldExample_i}100000^100   I tried this and can't see any boost in debug mode

Comment: Does it treat this field as a wildcard and that the reason it do not boost it?